# g++ does not ignore "deprecated-declaration" + "Werror" error when using "-Wno-deprecated"

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, g++, deprecated

The same case from the strikethrough case down here. I have a deprecated function call, and it gives an error. I want to ignore it for now. I can use `#undef` but I prefer using a *`"-Wno-deprecated"`* compilation flag, but for some reason I stil get the same error.

I have two modules with calls to the depracted functoin:

```
SSH_DEPRECATED LIBSSH_API int ssh_get_pubkey_hash(ssh_session session, unsigned char **hash);
// SSH_DEPRECATED == __attribute__ ((deprecated))
// as can be seen from:
//   #define SSH_DEPRECATED __attribute__ ((deprecated))
```

Module **A** (the errornous module) ouputs a "is depracted" warning made error. I assumed the reason I saw only one error was because the compilation flags of **A** included `-Werror`. However, both of the modules include the same flag.

However, module **B** has something different. **A** includes `libssh.h` from *`arm-buidroot-linux-gnueabi`* where **B** includes that `libssh.h` and another copy of `libssh.h` (I assume the 2nd copy is a copy-paste of an older version of `libssh.h`).

I assumed that the `SSH_DEPRECATED` does not appear on the 2nd `libssh.h`, but I was wrong, so now I'm not what could be the reason.

Currently I got it to work by removing the *`-Werror`* in **A**, but this is bad since:

1. I don't know what is the root cause (i.e. how come it works in **B**)
2. I do want that flag [*`-Werror`*] (this can be solved by adding *`-Wno-deprecated`*
    and then returning the *`-Werror`*, but I don't think of it as a good solution. More like a hack)

**My question:** What in **A** can cause this deprecated warning that does not apply in **B**?

*Using `powerpc-linux-gnu-g++ (Sourcery G++ Lite 4.3-74) 4.3.2`*

Note: I know that *[**deprecated** Indicates that the name or entity declared with this attribute is deprecated, that is, the use is allowed, but discouraged for some reason.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/deprecated)*

Comment: could be many things. eg in gcc you can silence warnings when a header is included via `-isystem`

Comment: `#undef SSH_DEPRECATED #include ... #define SSH_DEPRECATED ...`

Comment: @YSC how's that better than my `-Wno-deprecated`? I don't want to ignore, but to fix

Comment: This is not a solution, this is one of many things that could make the warning not to appear in `B`. We cannot _guess_. At this point, this is just opinions you're asking.

Comment: @user463035818 so you think the cause is warning suppression?

Comment: the symptom is that a warning is surpressed, what is the cause i have no clue ;)

Comment: @YSC in that case, no such `#undef` exists. However, `#ifdef __GNUC__
#define SSH_DEPRECATED __attribute__ ((deprecated))
#else
#define SSH_DEPRECATED
#endif` so, could that change something?

Comment: Just so I understood: You have two compilation units in individual compiler invocations, using identical `libssh.h` (except for path) and identical compiler options, both using the deprecated function, but only one giving the warning? In that case the exact compiler command line and MCVEs of the two compilation units would be helpful.

Comment: After resolving the 1st error with the -Werror removal trick and clean build, I got the same error on the 2nd module... :-( I'm deleting the question in a few minutes. Thanks for all your input guys!!

Comment: Your build system may also be filtering the output or messing with compiler flags.

Comment: If you expect your post to be read by actual people, then I suggest you don't do something ghastly like striking through the whole of the text you still refer too!

Comment: I don't want a reader to read the original too much, only as a reference, and even that is not required as I tried to explain the case shortly in the 3 lines of text I did not strikthrough. The reminder of the strikthroug text was for those who already read and commented above